# Is there a way to compare 2 unsupervised models?

Tags: nlp, lda, topic-modeling

I understand it’s usually difficult to evaluate unsupervised models. However, since I’m new to NLP, I figured I’d ask to see if there’s a way to compare 2 topic models. I have an STM and an LDA models, but if someone asks how do I choose one vs the other, I have no answer. Is there a way where given the data I have, I can show some metric that I can compare between models and state with some degree of confidence the LDA is better or worse than STM?

Comment: https://twitter.com/johnny_kelsey/status/1133823798401228800?s=20

Comment: You can also run clustering many times and use the stability of the clusters as a metric, https://twitter.com/leland_mcinnes/status/1133902675517591556?s=20

Comment: Similar ideas in more detail are discussed in this podcast https://twimlai.com/twiml-talk-276-topic-modeling-for-customer-insight-at-usaa-with-william-fehlman/ ... I’m on a phone, or else I’d compile these into an actual answer

Answer (score 0):

Gensim, for Python, [has a tutorial](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/howtos/run_compare_lda.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-howtos-run-compare-lda-py) showing how to compare LDA models. Since (I believe) the outputs of STM and LDA should be more or less the same, you should be able to do the same analysis.

For what it's worth, I don't know that there is a universally-accepted way to compare models. I've dabbled with it in R doing something similar to the Gensim tutorial. It can be a bit of a headache and (at least in my case) the results weren't super clear.